# javascript : Cannot access member function

Tags: javascript

NEWBIE question.

I cannot access member function. What am I doing wrong?

```
index.js ->
var abc = require('./def');
var foo = new abc();
foo.zxc(); 

def.js ->
var bar = function(){
// do something
    var zxc = function(){
        // do something
    }
}
module.exports = def;
```

When I run in brwoser console it shows :

TypeError:foo.zxc is not a function

Answer (score 2):

Because `zxc` is just a local variable not accessible from outside of the the `bar` function. You can change it to

```
var bar = function() {
   // do something
    this.zxc = function(){
        // do something
    }
}
```

Now, `zxc` is an own property of the constructed object so it will work.

Comment: @kalpa are you sure that def.js is exporting function `bar` ? because it doesn't look like it in the code you posted…

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following:

```
// index.js ->
var abc = require('./def');
var foo = new abc.bar();
foo.zxc(); 

// def.js ->
var bar = function(){
// do something
    this.zxc = function(){
        // do something
    }
}
module.exports.bar = bar;
```

The main difference is you are now exporting the `bar() {...}` constructor which can then be used off of the `abc` required in module?